# Is there a correct alternative to cancelAndHoldAtTime when the browser does not support this?

Tags: web-audio-api

Using WAA (Web Audio Api) I am using `exponentialRampToValueAtTime` to create a fade in and out that can be cancelled for the user pressing the "stop" button.

The stops function looks something like this:

```
 this._gainNode.gain.cancelAndHoldAtTime(this._AudioContext.currentTime);    
this._gainNode.gain.exponentialRampToValueAtTime(0.000001, this._AudioContext.currentTime + fadeDuration);
```

The complete function is wrapped in a Promise because I need to do something else after the stop (`fadeDuration`);

The problem is that in some browsers `cancelAndHoldAtTime` does not exit and I get some nasty clips that I do not know how to prevent. The same happens with `cancelValuesAndHoldAtTime` that is even less supported.

I tried with `cancelScheduledValues` but it does not help.

Is there a workaround or correct alternative to `cancelAndHoldAtTime`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although maybe the best alternative for `cancelAndHoldAtTime` is [the one recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48039883/1255819) for [Raymond Toy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4167016/raymond-toy), to completely remove the clip and any glitches what I ended up doing was making a "Main Gain" between the oscillator Gain and the `destination`

OSC -> oscGain -> mainGain -> speakers.

Before I do anything I close the `mainGain` and then `cancelScheduledValues` and all the other stuff to the `oscGain`

Comment: If you don't really care about the "hold" part of `cancelAndHoldAtTime`, then this is a perfectly fine solution.  Not sure what "close the mainGain" really means, but presumably, it's not just setting the gain to zero instantly because that will cause a glitch.  Maybe that's ok? If not, use a linear ramp to zero or `setTargetAtTime` to transition smoothly to 0.

Answer (score 2):

You can do an approximation by calling `setValueAtTime(v, t)` where `t` is the context time at which the user pressed the stop button and `v` is the estimated value of the exponential at time `t`.

You'll probably still get a glitch, but it will probably be much better than using just `cancelScheduledValues`.

This is the reason why `cancelAndHoldAtTime` was added to the API.

Comment: You mean instead of `cancelScheduledValues` of before it ?

Comment: Also, `v` would be `gainNode.gain.value` at `ctx.currentTime`. Or I am understanding it incorrectly ?

Comment: Yes that's the value for `v`. But remember that the value you read will probably be behind the actual value (if it's automated in some way) since you're running on the main thread and the automations are on the independent audio thread.